# How do I get C code intermixed with SASS with cuobjdump?

Tags: c, cuda

I am not sure what I am doing something in wrong way, essentially I would like to get readable assembly, intermixed with C calls.

Here is some example code:

#### `example.cu`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void kernel()
{
    unsigned long a, b, c;

    a = 255;
    b = 10;

    c = a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    cudaFree(0);

    kernel<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
```

As I looked into `cuobjdump -h` (emphasis mine):

> `--dump-sass` (`-sass`)
>           Dump assembly for all listed device functions. **Cuda source is 
>           intermixed** with the listed assembly in case option **-G** was specified to 
>           `nvcc` during compilation, and **if the source files can still be found**.

I compile it with (thus `example.cubin` file is created):

```
nvcc -G -cubin -arch=sm_30 --ptxas-options=-v example.cu
```

Then I run:

```
cuobjdump -sass --function _Z6kernelv example.cubin
```

The output contains assembly instruction, but I see no C code anywhere:

```
code for sm_30
    Function : _Z6kernelv
.headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM30 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM30)"
    /*0000*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x44];             /* 0x2800400110005de4 */
    /*0008*/                   ISUB R1, R1, 0x8;                 /* 0x4800c00020105d03 */
    /*0010*/                   S2R R0, SR_LMEMHIOFF;             /* 0x2c000000dc001c04 */
    /*0018*/                   ISETP.GE.AND P0, PT, R1, R0, PT;  /* 0x1b0e00000011dc23 */
    /*0020*/               @P0 BRA 0x30;                         /* 0x40000000200001e7 */
    /*0028*/                   BPT.TRAP 0x1;                     /* 0xd00000000400c007 */
    /*0030*/                   IADD R0, R1, RZ;                  /* 0x48000000fc101c03 */
    /*0038*/                   MOV R2, R0;                       /* 0x2800000000009de4 */
    /*0040*/                   MOV R3, RZ;                       /* 0x28000000fc00dde4 */
    /*0048*/                   MOV R2, R2;                       /* 0x2800000008009de4 */
    /*0050*/                   MOV R3, R3;                       /* 0x280000000c00dde4 */
    /*0058*/                   MOV R4, c[0x0][0x24];             /* 0x2800400090011de4 */
    /*0060*/                   MOV R5, RZ;                       /* 0x28000000fc015de4 */
    /*0068*/                   IADD R2.CC, R2, R4;               /* 0x4801000010209c03 */
    /*0070*/                   IADD.X R3, R3, R5;                /* 0x480000001430dc43 */
    /*0078*/                   MOV32I R4, 0xff;                  /* 0x18000003fc011de2 */
    /*0080*/                   MOV R5, RZ;                       /* 0x28000000fc015de4 */
    /*0088*/                   MOV R4, R4;                       /* 0x2800000010011de4 */
```

I haven't found any option to tell explicitely where `example.cu` is located (it is in the same directory though). OTOH Nsight Eclipse Edition with the same code is clearly able to display SASS with C code (within debugging session in Dissassembly window):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, currently, using `cuobjdump`.  The referenced `cuobjdump` documentation/command line help is in error.

Comment: So it's clearly a bug. Are there any other options? May be `nvdisasm` ? It's rather strange that nsight somehow does not have such limitation.

Comment: Something like it is possible with `nvdisasm` in CUDA 6.5 (it is a new feature in CUDA 6.5 AFAIK). You'll need to compile your code to a cubin, and then use `nvdisasm -g` to dump the cubin. It gives you line references, not the actual line of source. I'm not sure it will work for every `nvcc` option, I compiled to cubin with `-g -G -lineinfo`, you can try to see if any of those options are actually needed on the compile step. The `-g` command line option for `nvdisasm` is documented in the [nvdisasm documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#nvdisasm-options).

Comment: Thank you for that, I also learned that with `nvcc -G --source-in-ptx -ptx example.cu` I can get PTX intermediate assembly interlaced with C code, which seems to be documented much better (vide PTX ISA) than SASS.